# File in binary form

Tags: c, file, binary

I want to write data into the file in binary form.

I was trying using the mentioned below

```
FILE *fp = fopen("binaryoutput.rgb888", "ab+");

for(int m=0; m<height; m++)
{
   for (int n=0; n< width; n++)        
   {                            
    temp = (pOutputImg+m*3+n*3); // here pOutputImg & temp is a pointer to a unsigned char  
    fprintf(fp,"%u",*temp);             
   }        
}
fclose(fp);
```

I am able to get data which is strored at pOutputImg but not in binary form.

Can anyone guide me the correct step..

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is very difficult to figure out the intent. What are the types of temp and pOutputImg? Why do you multiply both m and n by 3? Shouldn't one of them be multiplied by the other's dimension?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : That is for obtaining the data in correct format for RGB888.. by writing that file in binary format will give me the correct format for RGB888 image..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace fprintf() with fwrite().

Ex:

```
fwrite(temp, sizeof(*temp), 1, fp);
```

The whole purpose of fprintf() is to format binary data as readable ascii ... the exact opposite of what you want. fwrite() is for directly writing binary data.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a pixmap of rgb triplets, you can write the binary data with one line:

```
fwrite(pOutputImg, 3, height * width, fp);
```